# Are there questions in Miklos Bona's "A Walk through Combinatorics" that are unsolved?

Tags: combinatorics, publishing

I am trying to figure out what exactly is meant by the line (in the preface), "The difficulty level of an exercise with more than one + sign may be comparable to an independent publication."  Can you publish a paper on any of the exercises?  Are any of them unsolved?

(Also, I doubt I'm using the best tags.  Any input on which tags to use will be greatly appreciated.)

Comment: No. These are results that *at the time of their discovery* could have made a paper.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks